# Data frame subset with specified sum of elements

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Having a data frame like this:

```
   df <- data.frame(a=c(31, 18, 0, 1, 20, 2), 
   b=c(1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1), 
   c=c(12, 0, 9, 8, 10, 3))

   > df
      a b  c
   1 31 1 12
   2 18 0  0
   3  0 0  9
   4  1 3  8
   5 20 1 10
   6  2 1  3
```

How can I do a random subset so the sum of rows and columns is equal to a value, i.e , 100?

Comment: Please show the expected result for your example.

Comment: Are you trying to find a particular subset of rows and columns which has sum 100? That doesn't sound very random.

Comment: I've tried `sample(1:nrow(df), 100, replace=TRUE)` but with that we obtain a vector. The intention is to sub-sample a population so the size is reduced without changing the relative frequencies of the elements of this. i.e, Sampling a forest, noting down the species (columns), and number of individuals in different areas (rows).

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you're trying to sample a subset of the rows and columns of your matrix so that they sum to a target value.

You can use integer optimization to accomplish this. You'll have a binary decision variable for each row, column, and cell, and constraints to force the cell values to be equal to the product of the row and column values. I'll use the `lpSolve` package to do this, because it has a convenient mechanism to get multiple optimal solutions. We can then use the `sample` function to select between them:

```
library(lpSolve)
get.subset <- function(dat, target) {
  nr <- nrow(dat)
  nc <- ncol(dat)
  nvar <- nr + nc + nr*nc
  # Cells upper bounded by row and column variable values (r and c) and lower bounded by r+c-1
  mat <- as.matrix(do.call(rbind, apply(expand.grid(seq(nr), seq(nc)), 1, function(x) {
    r <- x[1]
    c <- x[2]
    pos <- nr + nc + (r-1)*nc + c
    ltc <- rep(0, nvar)
    ltc[nr + c] <- 1
    ltc[pos] <- -1
    ltr <- rep(0, nvar)
    ltr[r] <- 1
    ltr[pos] <- -1
    gtrc <- rep(0, nvar)
    gtrc[nr + c] <- 1
    gtrc[r] <- 1
    gtrc[pos] <- -1
    return(as.data.frame(rbind(ltc, ltr, gtrc)))
  })))
  dir <- rep(c(">=", ">=", "<="), nr*nc)
  rhs <- rep(c(0, 0, 1), nr*nc)

  # Sum of selected cells equals target
  mat <- rbind(mat, c(rep(0, nr+nc), as.vector(t(dat))))
  dir <- c(dir, "=")
  rhs <- c(rhs, target)

  res <- lp(objective.in=rep(0, nvar),  # Feasibility problem
            const.mat=mat,
            const.dir=dir,
            const.rhs=rhs,
            all.bin=TRUE,
            num.bin.solns=100  # Number of feasible solutions to get
            )
  if (res$status != 0) {
    return(list(rows=NA, cols=NA, subset=NA, num.sol=0))
  }
  sol.num <- sample(res$num.bin.solns, 1)
  vals <- res$solution[seq((sol.num-1)*nvar+1, sol.num*nvar)]
  rows <- which(vals[seq(nr)] >= 0.999)
  cols <- which(vals[seq(nr+1, nr+nc)] >= 0.999)
  return(list(rows=rows, cols=cols, subset=dat[rows,cols], num.sol=res$num.bin.solns))
}
```

The function returns the number of subset with that sum and returns the randomly selected subset:

```
set.seed(144)
get.subset(df, 1)
# $rows
# [1] 1
# $cols
# [1] 2
# $subset
# [1] 1
# $num.sol
# [1] 14

get.subset(df, 100)
# $rows
# [1] 1 2 4 5
# $cols
# [1] 1 3
# $subset
#    a  c
# 1 31 12
# 2 18  0
# 4  1  8
# 5 20 10
# $num.sol
# [1] 2

get.subset(df, 10000)
# $rows
# [1] NA
# $cols
# [1] NA
# $subset
# [1] NA
# $num.sol
# [1] 0
```